# How to add image source tag to WordPress Header Template?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, svg

I seem to be having a problem linking my image. I'm trying to link the logo.svg to my header , yet it's not working. My folder structure is down below. I believe It's linking to the right path.

/logo.svg" />

http://oi61.tinypic.com/311km1k.jpg

Here is the code: pastebin.com/TQ75PDdJ

Comment: Please add your code instead of posting pictures of your editor.

Comment: `Not working`... Please copy and paste the resulting generated HTML from your page. I imagine there'll be a space or two slashes or similar in the img href. (And please do post your actual code instead next time)

Comment: Yeah my bad @ThomasBormans, here is the code http://pastebin.com/TQ75PDdJ

Answer (score 0):

Open bugzilla when page loads to see if you have any errors or simply view the source and click the link for the SVG file. can you provide a link to the website?

Comment: You can go ahead and view my source code  pastebin.com/TQ75PDdJ